# PaperStreamIP twain SDk integration in vb6 application

Tags: vb6, scanning, twain

We have installed PaperstreamIP twain sdk in our machines to scan a document through VB6 application. Could you please suggest us how to integrate that sdk in the application.do we need to download any specific dll to support twain sdk.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for PaperStream? Surely that's something they would explain?